# VS Code: How to reduce the minimum window size of Visual Studio Code through settings.json or some other method

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to know if there is a way to reduce the minimum window size of VS Code - currently the window size can be reduced in width up to around 600px where there is a hard limit and you are unable to reduce it further this is different to most other program windows which can be reduced much more.

I want to be able to reduce the width even further to have more spare space on my screen - is there a way to do this through settings.json or some other method to be able to reduce the VS code minimum window size limit.

Comment: I personally don't like encouraging recommending extensions, as that's off topic, but others probably will if they know of one, but as far as native support is concerned; re: `is there a way to do this through settings.json` no there is not at this time. You are always welcome to create a feature request on their github

Answer (score 1):

The minimum size ehrn the panel is on the bottom is being reduced from 600px to 400px in v1.50 (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_50.md#new-minimum-window-width-when-panel-is-on-the-bottom).

> New minimum window width when panel is on the bottom
>
> When the panel is on the bottom rather than on the side, the minimum
> window width is 400px instead of 600px.

There is no way in the settings to change the minimum size.